# What is the stable9 theme? When should I use it instead of stable?

Tags: theming, 9

https://www.drupal.org/node/3066038

Has this cryptic statement:

> However, defaulting to base theme: stable prevents automatic updates to the next major version of Drupal, since each major version may have a different version of "the stable theme"

and proceeds to list these without any explanation.

The READMEs in the relevant directories are no help.

> Warning: Themes that opt out of using Stable as a base theme will need
> continuous maintenance as core changes, so only opt out if you are prepared to
> keep track of those changes and how they affect your theme.

> Warning: Themes that decide to not use Stable 9 as a base theme will need
> continuous maintenance as core changes, so only opt out if you are prepared to
> keep track of those changes and how they affect your theme.

I have a Drupal 8 theme, I am upgrading to Drupal 9 should I specify stable or stable9? This is really confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **My theme is extending Drupal 8 Stable, what should I do?**
>
> Upgrading to a Stable 9 can be a tedious task. Therefore, we have
> decided to continue to support previous versions of Stable. Drupal 8
> Stable will be shipped in Drupal 9 along Stable 9. Drupal 8 Stable
> will be deprecated during the Drupal 9 lifecycle to be removed in
> Drupal 10 so that the theme can be moved into a contrib project.

https://www.drupal.org/node/3107179

Comment: _facepalm_ Opening `stable.info.yml` finds `description: A default base theme using Drupal 8.0.0's core markup and CSS.` Why on earth was this not named **stable8** ?

Comment: They kept the old machine name because that theme is deprecated in Drupal 9. It would not make sense to change its machine name, which would not be a BC change, and then deprecate the theme.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use it you have to enable the theme before using it.

e.g. drush theme:enable stable9

From the .info

description: A base theme using Drupal 9.0.0's core markup and CSS.

So in other words all the new markup in html plus the old markup, css etc in d9+